# Controller still calls method after exception is thrown

Tags: mysql, jpa, exception, spring-data-jpa

I would like my controller not to execute the method called in that controller if the JSON I input generates an Exception.

Here is my controller

```
@PostMapping
    public BankUser save(@RequestBody BankUser bankUser) throws SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException {
        accountService.save(bankUser);
        return userService.save(bankUser);
    }
```

I want to automatically create an account when a new user is added, unfortunately, if I try to pass a duplicate user, the user is not created, but the account for that user still is created, with help of the save method in the accountService layer.

My question is if I could somehow handle the exeption thrown by the controller, in a way that I call the save() method of the accountRepository only if the controller does not throw any error.

Answer (score 0):

Adding @Transactional made it work

```
@PostMapping
@Transactional
public BankUser save(@RequestBody BankUser bankUser) throws SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException{
    accountService.save(bankUser);
    return userService.save(bankUser);
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).